# Table where first column has max width and second column has text ellipsis

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I'm working on a table layout that needs CSS love. My goal is simple: 2 rows, 2 cols. The table will have a fixed width of say 250px, the first col will have a max width of say 100px (but the text inside can wrap), and the second col should occupy the remainder of the table width, but should not wrap and should instead have a text ellipsis at the end of the first line.

Here's my current approach. You'll see the second column makes the table wider than 250px:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f7f5eb;
  color: #cf6824;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.tc {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.truncate {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='tc truncate'>Wow such CSS very style</div>
    <div class='tc no-wrap'>That was a very loud beep. I don't even know if this is working.</div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='tc truncate'>Mark? Mark? Are you there?</div>
    <div class='tc no-wrap'>Are you screening your calls? It's Mom? We wanted to call and say we love you.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, my second col (`.no-wrap`) is extending the table width, which I'd like to prevent.

How can I achieve the goal expressed above? Any pointers would be very welcome!

Comment: Why are you using divs if you want a table? That just makes for a bunch of extra markup and CSS.

Comment: Then maybe [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). I'd not reinvent the HTML table with CSS for no good reason. That's somewhat an obsolete approach.

Comment: Your requirements are a bit fuzzy. I'm not sure what "max width" means if not 100%, and then there's no second column.